# Global stock market valuations

Tags: equities, valuation

I am looking for reasonably up to date resources on global stock market valuations by country, using e.g. CAPE and PE. In the past I have used this resource: [starcapital.de](https://www.starcapital.de/en/research/stock-market-valuation), but the updates have been discontinued (I have asked). Are there any other, roughly similar, resources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yardeni has lots of great valuation information. Below is a link to the forward P/E ratio by country, as requested. The update date is March 10, and the frequency is weekly, so this is probably as timely as one would ever need it to be if one is doing fundamental investing.

https://www.yardeni.com/pub/mscipe.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I usually check it via iShares website for country specific ETFs. They have ETFs for many countries and it can be used as a good proxy to invest easily to these countries. For example, this site provides P/E and other information for Singapore: https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239678/ishares-msci-singapore-capped-etf